# ImageView Size and position

Tags: android, android-imageview

How can i dynamically change size and position of ImageView?

1. User have to press the button of resizing and imageView begins to be scalable
2. user can change position of imageView

I think it have to be like instagram stickers or something like that. But i find only how to scale image inside ImageView and how to set a new value to imageView width and hieght, but i dont understand how to make it dynamically.

Is this the right way to change position of imageView? :

```
image.setY(number);
image.setX(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Resize:

```
imageView.getLayoutParams().height= 24;
imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 48;
```

Re-position use `imageView.setX()` and `imageView.setY()` as you mentioned above.

Comment: No, it's normal method of Android